# Search-wrapping: restart from pos1 when reaching EOF

Tags: visual-studio-code

Given a situation like this:

```
 [1] abc
 [2] foo
 [3] ghi
 [4] foo
 [5] more
 ...
 EOF
```

When searching for "foo" and the match in line #4 is highlighted, I'd like  search to auto-wrap and restart ot the beginning of the file. (I may have been editing in #3 when I started the search and so "Find next" should take me #2, possibly with a small no-clicks-requiring message that it restarted at top).

I can't find a way to achieve this - but I also can't believe it shouldn't be possible. Surely I can't be the only searcher around ;-)  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That's already what happens, at least on a fresh installed Visual Studio Code 1.31.1. Your search does wrap-around after the end of the file.

(Actually... I came across this answer since I am searching for a way to DISABLE this feature. Sadly, after days of searching this question is all I found.)

Comment: @Kar.me For a new setting to disable "search wrap", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158475/disable-search-wrap-in-vs-code

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark, I will test it as soon as my editor will we able to update from current 1.44.2 to 1.45