# Disable "search wrap" in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to disable "search wrapping" in VS code?

I.e. prevent the search from starting back at the top again after reaching the last occurrence of the search term in the file?

Comment: Related question on SU - https://superuser.com/questions/1462357/visual-studio-code-search-word-without-wrap-around .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE** !!

A setting is being added to v1.45 to disable "search wrapping".  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/92243

> Editor > Find: Loop

default is enabled, it will loop or wrap.

---

---------------- old answer:

No, apparently not.  See this issue: [disable search wrap](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46504).  That issue was closed due to lack of interest in 2018.

Comment: although the issue is closed, it still allows upvotes and comments so if you're reding this, please go in and give it an upvote

Answer (score 3):

In Preferences > Settings > Open Settings (Json)
Add:

```
"editor.find.loop": false
```