# VS Code - On compare show notification reached end of file

Tags: visual-studio-code, compare

On VS Code, when comparing file revisions and going through next changes,

I don't have notification of end of file

I expect a notification similar to eclipse's popup

[image]

Is there option to get me notify next change is from the beginning of the file?

I want to avoid going through same changes more than once

**EDIT**

Found similar fix on [editor search wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158475/disable-search-wrap-in-vs-code)

> disable "search wrapping". See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/92243

> Editor > Find: Loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open feature request for VS Code: [Stop loop to next change at last change of file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120709)